# Pop an element from exploded string and convert remaining array to string

Tags: php, arrays, explode

If I have a name, "Jane & John Doe" and would like to split the two like so: `$first = "Jane & John"` and `$last = "Doe"`. How do I do that? I know I should have something like this:

```
$name = "Jane & John Doe";
$name = explode(" ", $name);
$first = array_shift($name);
$last = array_pop($name);
```

I know that will only give me "Jane" and "Doe". Can I do the `array_pop()` first and then convert the rest of the array to a string?

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: I don't know how to do that in php.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about the split rule...otherwise in this particular example, you can just do `$last=array_pop($name); $first=implode(" ",$name);`.

Comment: Or better yet, read up on regex. Just because clumsy explode and shifting workarounds are commonplace doesn't mean they're the best option here.

Comment: You can use http://phpfiddle.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

You explode the string based on the space character.
You then "pop" the last element of the array into $last.
The remaining members of the array are then imploded, using the space character as the "glue"

```
$name = "Jane & John Doe";
$exploded = explode(" ", $name);
$last = array_pop($exploded);
$first = implode(" ", $exploded);
echo $first . " " . $last;
```

You can learn a whole lot more from [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). It has a lot of examples to go with it.

This is just a method of doing it. There are other ways of achieving your goal. Just be creative ..  :-)